# How can I round a number, x, scanned from a file, to i decimal places, scanned from same file in C?

Tags: c, rounding

R x i [Round Reals ]
Round double value x to i significant decimal places

example: 
this is scanned from the file: R 3.1415 2
so I need to print out 3.14

doing a big loop, has other functions
so far: 
else if (operate == "R")
printf("\n");

dont know what to put...help?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
double number;
int places;
fscanf(file, "%lf %d", &number, &places);
printf("%.*f\n", places, number);
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf('%.2f', your_number_var)` will format to two decimal places.

Comment: the number of decimal places that I have to round to are read from the file. So depending on what i is, that's how much it needs to round x to.

Comment: As nmichaels said. Build the format string on-the-fly with sprintf: `format = sprintf('%%.%df', 2); printf(format, your_number_var);`

Comment: @nmichaels how could i go about doing that?

Comment: Don't do what Marc said. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `sprintf` your format string like others say, you can do everything in one shot:

`printf("%.*f", precision, number)`